# innerHTML and event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, delegation

I have a containing div that has multiple divs within which is updated every 25ms using innerHTML (for performance reasons). I have tried using event delegation to capture events but nothing I seem to do captures the click event. I think this may be due to the speed that the contents are getting updated. Any ideas would be very welcome.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = $('#gCanvas')[0];

    $(document.body).delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {
        console.log(e.target);
    });

    var sprites = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sprites[i] = {x: i+10, y: i+10};
    }


    var doIt = function () {
        var s = '';

        for(var i = 0; i < sprites.length; i++) {
            var spr = sprites[i];
            spr.x++;
            spr.y++;

            s+= '<a id="s'+i+'" class="s" style="left:'+sprites[i].x+';top:'+sprites[i].y+'"></a>';
        }

        canvas.innerHTML = s;
    };
    //doIt();
    setInterval(doIt, 50);
});
```

Comment: Why are you updating so quickly?

Comment: refreshing every 25ms might be a bit extreme?

Comment: I've updated post with code.
I'm trying to create a game, and 25ms is 40fps. It seems to start registering clicks at >50ms (but not all the time) which is too low an fps.

Answer (score 1):

it easy if you use jquery. there is a [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, but i am not sure if it quick enough. alternatively you could try to check jquery source to find the .live() code and find the solution

**UPDATE**

if you are trying to make a game then you can try to use svg for good browsers and vml for bad ones.

Comment: The solution that `live` uses is event delegation, which the OP says he's doing.

Comment: SVG lacks the performance you can get compared with innerHTML

Comment: @Mark Gerrard: ok then you can try to detect the mouse position when user clicks on the overlay over the game viewport/field and find the nearest div.

Comment: I may have come up with a much tidy solution. Let me do some testing.